# Swift: Filter SwiftyJSON data in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller, swifty-json

I have data in JSON. I'm working with **SwiftyJSON**. My data is look like this:

```
[{
    "kode_customer": 1,
    "nama_customer": "Logam Jaya, UD",
    "alamat_customer": "Rajawali No 95",
    "kodepos": 60176,
    "kode_provinsi": 11,
    "gps_lat": -7.233834999999999,
    "gps_long": 112.72964666666667
}, {
    "kode_customer": 2,
    "nama_customer": "Terang, TK",
    "alamat_customer": "Raya Dukuh Kupang 100",
    "kodepos": 60225,
    "kode_provinsi": 11,
    "gps_lat": -7.285430000000001,
    "gps_long": 112.71538333333335
}, {
    "kode_customer": 3,
    "nama_customer": "Sinar Family",
    "alamat_customer": "By Pass Jomin No 295",
    "kodepos": 41374,
    "kode_provinsi": 9,
    "gps_lat": -6.4220273,
    "gps_long": 107.4748978
}, {
    "kode_customer": 4,
    "nama_customer": "Lancar Laksana, TB",
    "alamat_customer": "Jendral Sudirman No 69",
    "kodepos": 41374,
    "kode_provinsi": 9,
    "gps_lat": -6.4220273,
    "gps_long": 107.4748978
}]
```

How to display it on `tableView` and filter it using `UISearchController`. Here is my code:

```
class LocationSearchTable: UITableViewController {

    var custData: JSON = []   
    var filteredData: [String]!

    func getCustData() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cust_toko", ofType: "json")
        let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
        let json = JSON(data: jsonData!)

        self.custData = son
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(filteredData[indexPath.row])
    }
}

extension LocationSearchTable: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchText)
            filteredData = JSON(custData.filter{ JSON.Value() })

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

It got error like this: `'Value' (aka 'AnyObject') cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

Here is link to github for this question `https://github.com/lamfete/MapSearchDemo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my own question.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import MapKit

class LocationSearchTable: UITableViewController {

    var custData: JSON = []
    var dbTokos : [Toko] = []
    var filteredDataToko: [Toko]!

    var handleMapSearchDelegate: HandleMapSearch? = nil
    var vc = ViewController()

    func getCustData() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cust_toko", ofType: "json")
        let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
        let json = JSON(data: jsonData!)

        self.custData = Jon

        splitData()
}

    func splitData() {
        for(_, subJson):(String, JSON) in self.custData {
            if let name: String = subJson["nama_customer"].stringValue {
                if let address: String = subJson["alamat_customer"].stringValue {
                    if let city: String = subJson["kota"].stringValue {
                        if let province: String = subJson["provinsi"].stringValue {
                            if let lat: Double = subJson["gps_lat"].doubleValue {
                                if let long: Double = subJson["gps_long"].doubleValue {
                                    let toko = Toko(title: name,
                                                locationName: address,
                                                cityName: city,
                                                provinsiName: province,
                                                coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long))
                                    dbTokos.append(toko)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredDataToko.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
        cell.textLabel!.text = String(filteredDataToko[indexPath.row].title!)
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = String(filteredDataToko[indexPath.row].locationName) + ", " + String(filteredDataToko[indexPath.row].cityName) + ", " + String(filteredDataToko[indexPath.row].provinsiName)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let toko = Toko(title: filteredDataToko[indexPath.row].title!,
                        locationName: filteredDataToko[indexPath.row].locationName,
                        cityName: filteredDataToko[indexPath.row].cityName,
                        provinsiName: filteredDataToko[indexPath.row].provinsiName,
                        coordinate: filteredDataToko[indexPath.row].coordinate)

        handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPinZoomIn(toko)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension LocationSearchTable: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            filteredDataToko = searchText.isEmpty ? dbTokos : dbTokos.filter(
                {
                    (dataString: Toko) -> Bool in
                    return dataString.title?.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
                }
            )
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you initialize a string from a string (`title`, `locationName` etc. seem to be string anyway)?

Comment: so it won't optional

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get array from the JSON object with `arrayObject` after that you need to change your predicate key `name` to `customer_name` because there is no `key` name inside your json response, So change your code like this to only get customer_name from that result.

```
extension LocationSearchTable: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "nama_customer contains[cd] %@", searchText)
            if let array = custData.arrayObject as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                 let filterArr = array.filter{ searchPredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }
                 filteredData = filterArr.map({ String($0["nama_customer"])})
                 tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, It got 2 errors. 
First error is `'Value' (aka 'AnyObject') cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers` on `let filterArr = JSON(custData.filter{ JSON.Value() })` 

and the second error is `Use of unresolved identifier 'filterData'` on `filterData = filterArr.map {$0["nama_customer"]}`

Comment: error `Cannot convert value of type 'Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'` occurred on `let filterArr = JSON(custData.filter{ searchPredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) })` pointing to `$0`

Comment: still error, sir `Type 'Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') has no subscript members` on 'filteredData = filterArr.map { $0["nama_customer"] }' I added .stringValue after ["nama_customer"] but still error too.

Comment: compile time, sir. error is `Type 'Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') has no subscript members`

Comment: Check my edit, i have changed `if let array = custData.arrayObject as? [[String:AnyObject]] {`

Comment: still the same error sir, on this line  `filteredData = filterArr.map({ String($0["nama_customer"].stringValue)})`

Comment: Check my edit i have changed this line `let filterArr = array.filter{ searchPredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }`

Comment: it work, sir. But the answer is Optional. I added exclamation mark (!) behind the variable to unwrap the optional value, but the Optional still there.
`["Optional(Logam Jaya, UD)", "Optional(Sinar Family)", "Optional(Lancar Laksana, TB)"]`

Comment: Try to add `!` like this `String($0["nama_customer"])!`

Comment: Please accept and up vote the answer now it is working, it is printing optional in console, try to give value to label it will not display optional there.

Comment: yes, sir. I already tried this `String($0["nama_customer"])!`, but error.

Comment: Have you try to display value to label?

Comment: yes sir, i already display the value to label `cell.textLabel!.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]`

Comment: If it is displaying optional inside label, try like this `cell.textLabel!.text = String(filteredData[indexPath.row])`

Comment: optional still persist, sir :(

Comment: Is optional is printing on label with value?

Comment: yes sir, optional is printed on label with value. like this: `Optional(Logam Jaya, UD)`

Comment: Try like this `if let name = filteredData[indexPath.row] { cell.textLabel!.text =  name` or  `if let name = filteredData[indexPath.row] { cell.textLabel!.text =  name!`

Comment: error `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'`

Comment: Don't understand why are you getting this optional

Comment: Try `array!.filter{ searchPredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }` add `!` with array.

Comment: error `Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[[String : AnyObject]!]'`

Comment: Try to print `filterArr` object is it contains optional?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120494/discussion-between-lamfete-and-ndoc).